# Why does my df save one dictionary as two duplicate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Pizza', 'calories': 234}
print(pd.dataFrame(d))
```

When I try to turn it into a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(d)`, I get a dataframe with two duplicate rows of the same entry:

|  | id | name | calories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Pizza | 234 |
| 1 | 1 | Pizza | 234 |

I want the outcome to be only one row for each entry, not two.

I have tried using `pd.DataFrame(d)`and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)`. I know I can just use `df.iloc[0]` or remove duplicates and solve this issue, but why is duplicate even saved at all?
Pandas version is 1.4.2

Comment: Please post a [mre] since the code you posted won't run at all.

Comment: Which pandas version do you have? recent versions should complain that you need to pass an explicit index (`pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])`).

Comment: If I do `pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1])` I get the expected df with a single row.

Comment: I get a ValueError using both ```pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])``` and ```pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1])```, but as I mentioned below using ```pd.DataFrame([d])``` solved this. My pandas version is 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's this obvious to everyone, but personally I feel like a doofus finding this out now. the solution was to put the dict inside list brackets.
`pd.DataFrame([d])`

Comment: You should really add your pandas version in the question, recent pandas won't allow you the `pd.DataFrame(d)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is version dependent, but I can't even make a DataFrame just using the two lines you've mentioned. That said, you should be able to resolve this by making each value a list.

```
d = {'id': [1], 'name': ['Pizza'], 'calories': [234]}

pd.DataFrame(d)
```